Problem connecting to WalletConnect (Проблема с подключением кошелька)
Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой при разработке: если при подключении кошелька через WalletConnect в модальном окне в качестве провайдера выбрать WalletConnect, то появляется второе модальное окно, которое перекрывается первым и, если закрыть первое окно и попытаться закрыть второе, то второе окно начинает бесконечно открываться.
Разрабатываю на Next.js
Библиотеки и их версии:
"@web3modal/wagmi": "^5.1.8",
"viem": "^2.21.7",
"wagmi": "^2.12.11"
EDIT: English Translation of the above question.
Hi all. I encountered this problem during development: if, when connecting a wallet via WalletConnect, in a modal window you select WalletConnect as a provider, then a second modal window appears, which overlaps the first one, and if you close the first window and try to close the second one, the second window begins to open endlessly.
I develop on Next.js
Libraries and their versions:
"@web3modal/wagmi": "^5.1.8", "viem": "^2.21.7", "wagmi": "^2.12.11

English only, please

Could you please share the code snippet that is causing the issue?
